# Defining a function for later use in TikZ or pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Not sure what my problem is. I'm trying to define a function to later use in 3D plotting. As of now, I've tried to simplify the code as much as possible to find the error, so realize these are not the functions I am actually going to be using.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{r}{2}{%
    \pgfmathparse{1.6}%
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=center,view={135}{45}]
\addplot3[surf,variable=\u, variable y=\v,samples=40,
    domain=0:1, y domain=-pi:pi]
    ({r(u,v)},{0},{0});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture
\end{document}
```

I've also tried `\tikzset{declare function={r{\a,\b}=1.6;}}` and `\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={r(\a,\b)=1.6;}]` (which I realize are the same thing, but who knows).

The main error I'm getting seems to be "! Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point unit got an ill-formatted floating point number".

Comment: This happens because the function `r` is already defined (it's used for converting from radians to degrees). If you choose a unique function name, say `myfun`, everything works as expected.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was resolved by not using a reserved function name. (Minor issue solved in the comments.)